# RDP connection failed after logging into VPN (L2TP/IPSec) on a sever

Tags: windows, vpn, rdp, l2tp

I have a virtual machine Win 10, and I can connect to it via RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) from my local laptop. Now I want to establish a VPN (L2TP/IPSec) on the remote Win 10 to a third host, because I cannot connect to the third host from my local laptop. However, the connected RDP session to the Win10 failed after the VPN is established on the Win10. Actually, I also can visit the virtual machine (VM) Win10 through the control panel of the VM provider in the browser, so I can confirm that the VPN is indeed connected, but I cannot connect to it via RDP. And if I disconnect the VPN, the RDP connection would be OK again.

I have searched several related questions, such as [Prevent SSH connection lost after logging into VPN on server machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/649792/prevent-ssh-connection-lost-after-logging-into-vpn-on-server-machine), but it is for SSH and OpenVPN on Linux, not RDP and L2TP/IPSec for me.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the security settings on the RDP for the remote machine.  It sounds like you've got it set to a more strict policy where it requires the connections to be on the LAN.

On the Windows 10 machine goto 
 1. Control Panel > System and Security > System
 2. Select Remote Settings
 3. Check "Allow Remote Connections to this computer"
 4. Uncheck the "Allow Connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with network Level Auth."